# Django-registration: where is the views.py file to process form input and put it in the database?

Tags: django-registration

I'm trying to use django-registration to set up registration and authentication on a site I am building, and I've followed all the tutorials on the subject as closely as possible (e.g. http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/01/14/setting-up-django-registration/ among others). What I can't understand is where django-registration gets the views.py file to actually put form input into the database. I've tried using the default backend ('registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend') but there seems to be no actual views.py code in the registration folder to handle the form input.

It seems that it is supposed to import this from registration.views (i.e. from registration.views import activate, from registration.views import register), but again there is no views.py file included. Do you have to write one yourself? I assume the default backend is supposed to handle this itself, otherwise the backend is basically useless. Can anyone tell me what's missing here?

I apologize for asking such a noob question, but I've spent most of the past day or two working on this and have basically given up finding an answer without help. I'm new to django and python as well, so it would be wonderful if someone could help here...